# Google Send multi notifications to same device with different notification id Android

Tags: android, notifications

I have database and I have users, every one has a google id (registration id).

The first user registers a new account, it inserts 1 registration id in the database, 
then he registers with another account but after reinstalling the program  - so he inserts a new notification id but to the same device.

The problem happens here, when I send notification to all users, it sends to both accounts (old and new) in the same device, while it should only send one how to handle this thing?

I saw [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/36149645/google-send-multi-notifications-to-same-device-with-different-notification-id-an) answer but it didn't help.